# How can I create a responsive side menu layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, sidebar

here is the link to the site ( http://pavilioncreative.com/ ) hit refresh if you don't see a fullscreen gif as the background.

Im trying to get the red box to be alway centre no matter what size the screen is at. The problem is that the side menu has a position of fixed so the main content div is stretching fully 100% across the screen, under the side menu.

I think I might be going about it all wrong ?

```
    <html lang="en">

    <head>

    <title>FirstPage</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/text.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

<div class="wraper">

        <ul>

    <li class="menu" >

            <div class="menu_tab_wrap">

     <div class="menu_tab">

         <div class="menu_off_wrap">

         <div class="menu_off">

             <div class="barOne"></div>
             <div class="spacer"></div>
             <div class="barTwo"></div>
             <div class="spacer"></div>
             <div class="barThree"></div>

         </div>



        </div>

     </div> 

     </div>

     <div class="menu_tab_wrap_on">

     <div class="menu_tab_on">

         <div class="menu_on_wrap">

         <div class="menu_on">

             <div class="cross"></div>


         </div>



        </div>

     </div> 

     </div>

     <div class="logo_wrap">

            <div class="logo">

                <img src="img/logo.svg">

            </div>

         </div>


            </li>

              <section id="menu_out">

         <div class="menu_inner_wrap">

         <div class="menu_list">

         <ul class="menu_ul">

             <li class="menu_li"> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
             <span class="in_lable">Back to the home page</span>
             <li class="menu_li"> <a href="#">About</a> </li>
             <span class="in_lable">Find out more about me</span>
             <li class="menu_li"> <a href="#">Portfolio</a> </li>
             <span class="in_lable">Take a look at my past work</span>
             <li class="menu_li"> <a href="#">Contact Me</a> </li>
             <span class="in_lable">Get in contact with me</span>

        </ul>

         </div>



             </div>

     </section>

    <li class="content">
        <div class="content_wrap">

            <h1>test</h1>
            </div>
            </li>


    </ul>



        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">



        $(document).ready(function () {

    var hoverIn = false; //You need this counter to detect whether animate occurs.
$(".menu_tab").hover(function() {
    if (hoverIn)return; //if the hover is activated, it stops the function

  //I also took the liberty to help you add stop to prevent multiple hover. Feel free to implement that else where
  $(".barOne").stop(true, true).animate({
    "bottom": "+=5px"
  }, "fast");
  $(".barThree").stop(true, true).animate({
    "top": "+=5px"
  }, "fast");
  hoverIn = true;
}, function() {
    if (!hoverIn)return; //if the hover is deactivated, it stops this function
  $(".barOne").stop(true, true).animate({
    "bottom": "-=5px"
  }, 300);
  $(".barThree").stop(true, true).animate({
    "top": "-=5px"
  }, 300);
  hoverIn = false;
});

            });











       $(document).ready(function () {

        if($(window).width() > 700) {
             $(".menu_tab").click(function(){
             $("#menu_out").animate({"width": "30em"}, "slow");
             $(".menu_tab_wrap_on").stop().fadeIn();
             $(".menu_list").stop().delay( 400 ).fadeIn('slow');

            });

        }else{

             $(".menu_tab").click(function(){
             $("#menu_out").animate({"width": "100%"}, "slow");
             $(".menu_tab_wrap_on").stop().fadeIn();
             $(".menu_list").stop().delay( 400 ).fadeIn('slow');


            });

        }

                });


       $(document).ready(function () {

             $(".menu_tab_wrap_on").click(function(){
             $(".menu_tab_wrap_on").stop().hide('fast');
             $("#menu_out").animate({"width": "0em"}, "slow");
             $(".menu_list").stop().hide();
            });

                });











   </script>

    </body>


</html>




html{

    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* Prevent font scaling in landscape */

}

.wraper{

    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;

}


.wraper ul{

    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

}

.wraper ul li{

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;

}

.wraper ul .menu{

    width: 7%;
    min-width: 7em;
    max-width: 7em;
    background: black;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 20;
    float: left;


}


.wraper ul .content{

    background-color: blue;
    width: 93%;
    height: 70em;
    float: right;

}

.wraper ul .content .content_wrap{

    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: red solid 1px;


}





























.menu .menu_tab_wrap{

    position: relative;

}

.menu .menu_tab{

    width: 100%;
    background-color: #232323;
    height: 6em;
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}



.menu .menu_tab .menu_off_wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;



}

.menu .menu_tab .menu_off_wrap .menu_off{

   margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    position: relative;



}





.menu .menu_tab .menu_off_wrap .menu_off .barOne,.barTwo,.barThree{

    width: 3em;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;


}

.menu .menu_tab .menu_off_wrap .menu_off .spacer{

    width: 5em;
    height: 5px;


}



.menu .menu_tab_wrap_on{

    position: relative;
    display: none;





}

.menu .menu_tab_wrap_on .menu_tab_on{

    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    height: 6em;
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}



.menu .menu_tab_wrap_on .menu_tab_on .menu_on_wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;



}

.menu .menu_tab_on .menu_on_wrap .menu_on{

   margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;



}





.menu .menu_tab_on .menu_on_wrap .menu_on .cross{


  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;

  color: #232323;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;

}




.cross:before, .cross:after {
  position: absolute;

  content: ' ';
  height: 3em;
  width: 4px;
  background-color: #333;
}
.cross:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.cross:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}



.menu .logo_wrap{

    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;


}

.menu .logo_wrap .logo{

    width: 7em;
   margin: auto;
    position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
    padding-bottom: 2em;

}

.menu .logo_wrap .logo img{

    width: 70%;
    height: auto;

}
















#menu_out{

    background-color: #232323;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0em;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;

    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    border-right: 0.5em black solid;
    z-index: 10;


}


#menu_out .menu_inner_wrap{

    position: relative;



}


#menu_out .menu_list{

    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 5em;
    padding-bottom: 0em;
    display: none;
    position: relative;


}


#menu_out .menu_list .menu_ul{

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 4em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;



}

#menu_out .menu_list .menu_ul .menu_li{

    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;


}

#menu_out .menu_list .menu_ul .menu_li a{

    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    opacity: 0.8;


}


#menu_out .menu_list .menu_ul .menu_li a:hover{

    opacity: 1;

}


#menu_out .menu_list .menu_ul .in_lable{

    font-size: 15px;
    color: #80E577;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 10px;;


}


#menu_out .menu_inner_wrap .footer{

    width: 100%;

    margin: auto;

    position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
    height: 10em;

}












































@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

    .wraper ul .content{

    background-color: blue;
    width: 90%;
    height: 70em;
    float: right;

}


}




@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {

  .wraper ul .content{

    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70em;
    float: none;

}

    .wraper ul .menu{

    width: 100%;
    min-width: none;
    max-width: none;
    height: 5em;



}


    .menu .menu_tab{


    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    width: 6em;
    cursor: pointer;
        right: 0;
}



    .menu .logo_wrap{

    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;



}

.menu .logo_wrap .logo{

    width: 7em;
   margin: auto;
    position:absolute;
   bottom:0;

    padding-top: 1em;
        padding-bottom: 1em;

}


    .menu .menu_tab_wrap_on .menu_tab_on{

    width: 6em;

    height: 100%;

    right: 0;
    }



    #menu_out .menu_list{

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 8em;
    text-align: center;



}

    #menu_out .menu_list .menu_ul{

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0em;
        text-align: center;

}


    #menu_out .menu_list .menu_ul .menu_li a{

    font-size: 35px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    font-weight: 700;

}


#menu_out .menu_list .menu_ul .menu_li a .in_lable{

    font-size: 10px;
    color: #80E577;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;

}


    #menu_out{

       width: 0; 
        border-right: none;

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your CSS, I see this:

```
#content_wrap .content {
    max-width: 1050px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 700em;
     border: red solid 1px;
    margin-right: 7%;
    margin-left: 13%;
}
```

If you remove margin left and margin right, does it accomplish what you're after?

Example:

```
#content_wrap .content {
    max-width: 1050px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 700em;
     border: red solid 1px;
}
```

(When you remove `margin-left` and `margin-right`, `margin: auto` will then apply auto to margin top, right, bottom, and left.)

**UPDATE 2/25/2016:**

After following the steps above, you're most of the way there. However, if you want the content to change it's position (or re-center itself) as the menu expands out from the left side, it'll require a little more CSS and some JavaScript to add and remove a class. *Note: The above CSS changes are necessary for this to work*.

```
#content_wrap{
   //This should be the exact same with as the menu when it's not expanded out
    padding-left: 7em;
    //Set this to the same amount of time it takes for the menu to expand
    //This will animate the effect using CSS
    transition: 0.5s; 
}

#content_wrap.menu_showing {
   //This should be the exact same with as the menu when it's expanded out
    padding-left: 30em
}
```

Now just toggle that class on and off with JavaScript as you click the "Expand Menu" icon. Here's an example using jQuery:

```
$(".menu_tab").click(function(){
    $("#content_wrap").toggleClass("menu_showing");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. no this wouldn't work as the content in the red box would look like its slightly to the left due to the side menu overlaying the main content area.

Comment: You mention that you want the red box centered no matter what size. Do you want the red box to change it's position when the menu expands from the left side? Or should the red box stay exactly where it is even when the left side expands and takes up part of the screen?

Comment: Yes I want the box to be centred when the menu repositions to the top of the page I know how to do that but I don't know how to centre the div next to a fixed width div.    What I'm looking for is a fixed width div floated to the left side and then a responsive content div floated to the right side. the problem is that the fixed div is fixed so content in the content div won't be centred due to the fixed div overlaying the responsive content div                          This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve http://flipp.ca can you see how the content in the right content area is centred

Comment: Edited my answer, hopefully it's what you're looking for now.